# spring - use both simple SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and AnnotationMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Please tell me whether it is possible to use both SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and AnnotationMapping in spring mvc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have as many as you like. Each will be consulted until one of them says "yes, I have a mapping for that request".

Declare each of them in your beans file like any other bean, they'll be consulted in the order in which they appear.

However, by default, `DispatcherServlet` registers three different `HandlerMapping` beans automatically, `HttpRequestHandlerAdapter`, `SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter`, and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, so it's possible you don't need to do this yourself - you can mix-and-match handlers from all three styles, and Spring will handle it out of the box.